# How to select a check box in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Can any one pls help me out

There are many check boxes available with values and I have to choose a particular value in check box. I dont know how to choose a check box value in selenium webdriver

https://www.blueshieldca.com/fap/app/search.html

Comment: Are you saying 'Urgent care centers'?

Comment: No....In the URL I have shared it has the side menus namely category, type, Gender, Language etc....In that many check boxes are avialble.I have to choose a check box value from type

Comment: I don't see such menus in the above url; can u please update the right url?

Comment: In the above link the menus you have specified are hidden <input type="hidden" id="categoryType" value=""> And so its of no use. Can i have the right url?

Comment: U can do the following steps to go to that page: 1. Go to https://www.blueshieldca.com 2. Click on 'Find a Provider' 3. In search text box, type 'los' and select any value and click 'find now' 4.click on 'continu' in the pop-up 5. Now u can see many side menus with check boxes

Comment: I am unable to see the check boxes visually; and it doesnt makes any sense to check the hidden box

Comment: That are visible check boxes in UI For example under Gender I have two check boxes namely male & female....Like that many check boxes are available in that page

Comment: is this the url? https://www.blueshieldca.com/fap/app/search.html

Comment: @PrashanthSams in the URL you have pasted above, go to the "located near" text field and type "los", you will see a drop down and select a value from the drop down and then click on "find now" button. A pop up will be displayed and click on "continue" button in the pop up and in the new page you can see visible check boxes on left side.

Comment: Yes exactly.....My question is how to choose a value in check box

Comment: @Shyamala i have answered this. Please consider that. I have provided the logic on how can you choose the checkbox. You can use the logic to write the code to select a check box.

Comment: Oh! let me see; that is missing in the above description. I feel the question should be more generic

Comment: @Shyamala before people start voting down (negative voting) your question , please update it and make it more descriptive and to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works.. This will click the check box "General Medicine" under "Type" on left menu...

```
public class SampleUITest extends SeleneseTestBase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        try {
            driver.get("https://www.blueshieldca.com/fap/app/search.html");

            driver.findElement(By.id("location"))
                    .sendKeys("Locans, Fresno, CA");
            driver.findElement(By.className("findNow")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.className("continueBtn")).click();
            Thread.sleep(15000);
            driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath("//ul[@id='doctortypesmodule']/li[2]/input"))
                    .click();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works!!
Your actual issue is with wait

```
@BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        baseUrl = "https://www.blueshieldca.com/fap/app";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void Test01() throws Exception {

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/search.html");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='location']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='location']")).sendKeys(
                "Los Alamitos, Orange, CA");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='findNow']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@onclick='continueallPlans();']"))
                .click();

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By
                .xpath("//input[@onclick='javascript:results_OnProviderCompareClicked(this);']")));

        List<WebElement> ele = driver
                .findElements(By
                        .xpath("//input[@onclick='javascript:results_OnProviderCompareClicked(this);']"));
        System.out.println(ele.size());
        ele.get(0).click();
    }
```

---

**Prashanth Sams | seleniumworks.com**